# CSS3 animations working in every browser except Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Everything works perfectly in all browsers except Chrome. The fade in effects seems to work fine but the `floatInCommand` animation stutters and makes the Commend (a bootstrap container) lock in place after 1 second. I don't know if I need to add anything else besides "-webkit". I have looked at threads with similar problems and they all fix it by adding "-webkit".

```
.slide-in {
    -webkit-animation-name: floatInCommend;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatInCommend {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        top: -100%;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 75;
    }
}

.slide-in-footer {
    -webkit-animation-name: floatInFooter;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatInFooter {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.slide-in-nav {
    -webkit-animation-name: floatInFooter;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatInNav {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need both the -webkit, -moz, and non vendor prefix attributes.  Consider using a task runner and an autoprefixer to make sure you have all css vendor prefixes in place before publishing your code.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: sure! no problem.